# An illuminating riddle

Tags: riddle

> I come in storms,
>
> Or out of the blue,
>
> Some are good,
>
> But only a few.
>
> I steal your money,
>
> And also your time,
>
> I'm very valuable,
>
> But I don't cost a dime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are an

> Idea

I come in storms,

> From Brainstorming

Or out of the blue,

> When an idea randomly hits you

Some are good, but only a few.

> Most ideas are not great, but some are brilliant

I steal your money, and also your time

> Inspiration can lead to creative endeavors and investment of time/money

I'm very valuable, But I don't cost a dime.

> All great inventions and advancements were borne of an idea, and thoughts are free

Title: An illuminating riddle

> A light-bulb is a symbol for getting an idea

Comment: Correct, but I'll need an explanation to award the checkmark

Comment: Explanation Added

Comment: Every explanation correct

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Women?

I come in storms,

> [WNBA - Seattle Storm](http://storm.wnba.com/)

Or out of the blue,

> [Women's NCAA Basketball - Duke Blue Devils](http://www.goduke.com/SportSelect.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=4200&SPID=1846&SPSID=22760)

Some are good,

But only a few.

> Don't tell my mother I said this

I steal your money,

And also your time,

> Anyone here been married to one?

I'm very valuable,

But I don't cost a dime.

> Really valuable women are different than hookers.

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or upvote (:

Comment: this answer made my day